# How do I allow users to delete data on a website?

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlite

What I am trying to achieve is a website that allows users to log in, create flashcards, and delete them if needed. On the "review" page, users will see a table with all flashcards created and a delete button next to each row. The table is created by printing out row by row data from a sqlite database. I have come to a point where users are able to delete the rows from the table, but once they refresh the page, the deleted rows are back again since the deletion does not affect the sqlite database at all.

How should I go about allowing users to delete data from a sqlite database? I understand that I should be using db.exexcute("DELETE....") somehow, but I am unsure how I should link it to the delete button in the table.

Related HTML code

```
<script>
    function deleteRow(row){
        var d = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('review').deleteRow(d);
    }
</script>
<table id='review'>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Front</th>
        <th>Back</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in cards_created: %}
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
            <td>{{ row["front"] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row["back"] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row["tags"] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row["date"] }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Related Python Code

```
def review():

    """Review created cards"""
    cards_created = db.execute("SELECT front, back, tags, date FROM flashcards WHERE id = ? ORDER BY date DESC", session["user_id"])

    return render_template("review.html", cards_created=cards_created)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a record form the database, you should pass the delete information to the server where the delete will be done. The server will then send an updated page to the client.

Two parts need updating:

In the js script, get the row date from the selected row and send it to the server. I'm assuming the date field is unique for this user.

```
<script>
    function deleteRow(row){
        dt = row.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('td')[4].innerHTML; // date column
        doc = document.location.href  // current url
        // reload page from server
        document.location.href = doc + "?delDate=" + dt  //pass date for delete
    }
</script>
```

On the server, take the date parameter and delete that row from the database. I don't know how you retrieve URL parameters on the server side so I just added a parameter to the `review` method for this example.

```
def review(params):  # however you get params

    if params["delDate"]:  # user clicked delete, so remove row from database
         db.execute("DELETE flashcards WHERE id = ? and date = ?", session["user_id"], params["delDate"])
          
    """Review created cards"""
    cards_created = db.execute("SELECT front, back, tags, date FROM flashcards WHERE id = ? ORDER BY date DESC", session["user_id"])

    return render_template("review.html", cards_created=cards_created)
```

To make this cleaner, the flashcards table should have a unique id for the card so the date is not used. There is a risk that the date is not unique and several rows will be deleted.